# How to create a new Excel spreadsheet from within VB6

Tags: excel, vb6

I am attempting to create an Excel spreadsheet from within a VB6 application thus...

```
Set xl = New Excel.application
Set xlwbook = xl.Workbooks.Open(file_name)
Set xlsheet = xlwbook.Sheets.Item(1)
```

followed by

```
xlsheet.Cells(1, 1) = "Blah blah blah"
```

and so on.

I specifically want to create a new file every time this operation is performed. At the moment it returns a file not found error.

I'd like to know if this is the right approach, and if so, how I can request that a new file be created by the .Open method (or whatever method I should be using).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OPEN implies an existing sheet that you are trying to open.

You should be creating a new sheet.

Try this

```
Set xl = New Excel.application
Set xlwbook = xl.Workbooks.Add
Set xlsheet = xlwbook.Sheets.Item(1)
```

This will create an unsaved sheet. Once you are done with all the work, you have to save it.

```
xl.ActiveWorkBook.Save ("c:\myfilename.xls")
```

Comment: xl.ActiveWorkBook.SaveAs "c:\myfilename.xls"